# How to pass a NSMutableArray filled with objects to an UITableView and show the data

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

**Setup:**

`MainViewController` holds an `NSMutableArray` of objects. An object is an instance of my `NewContact` which has a `firstName` and a `contactImage` ivar. When I tap on `showAllContactsBtn` in `MainViewController` `AllContactsViewController` should show all object ivars (`firstNames` and `contactImages`) on the table.

I think the problem is that I do not pass the data properly to `AllContactsViewController` but can't figure out how to fix it. Worth to mention is that I do not see the  `NSLog` statements in `cellForRowAtIndex` so maybe the method will not be called at all?

**MainViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)showAllCBtnTapped:(id)sender
{
    AllContactsViewController *nAllCVC = [[AllContactsViewController alloc]init];
    nAllCVC.allContactsArray = self.contactsArray; // Properly passed the data???
    nAllCVC.delegate = self;
    nAllCVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

    [self presentModalViewController:nAllCVC animated:YES];
}
```

**AllContactsViewController.h**

```
@interface AllContactsViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

**AllContactsViewController.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdent = @"ContactCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdent];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdent];
    }

    NewContact *tempContact = [[NewContact alloc]init];

    tempContact = [self.allContactsArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    cell.textLabel.text = tempContact.firstName;

    NSLog(@"%@", tempContact.firstName);
    NSLog(@"Test......");

    cell.imageView.image = tempContact.contactPicture;

    [tableView reloadData];

    return cell;
}
```

**Note:**

As you can see `AllContactsViewController` was subclassed from `UIVIewController`, is this fine or do I have to subclass from `UITableViewController` despite I set the delegate and datasource properly?

Comment: did you put the datasource and delegate of table view in your allcontactsview controller ?

Comment: just to support the comment above. did you set the dataSource and delegate?   `yourTableView.delegate  = self; yourTableView.dataSource = self`

Comment: In IB I connected the `dataSource` and `delegate` (via ConnectionInspector) to `FilesOwner` which is `AllContactsViewController`.

Comment: @Marc: is the numberOfRowsInSection method working ? Please put a nslog on the numberOfRowsInSection , and also put a nslog for printing the array content

Comment: @Midhun MP > `numberOfRows` and `numberOfSections` will be called I see the `NSLogs` but when I want to to see whats in the array I get a bad access even when I refer to index 0 in the `array` so I did NOT get the data from `MainViewController`

Comment: Are you sure `self.contactsArray;` contains any values? Check it in the method `- (IBAction)showAllCBtnTapped:(id)sender`!

Comment: Yes the array in `MainViewController` does contain the objects. When I add this:     `NSLog(@"%i", [self.contactsArray count]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [self.contactsArray objectAtIndex:0]);` I get: `2012-08-15 14:30:36.140 Contacts+[9605:c07] 3
2012-08-15 14:30:36.142 Contacts+[9605:c07] <NewContact: 0x7f60970>`

Comment: Ok, I think you need to provide your full code of the two classes `AllContactsViewController` and `MainViewController`, otherwise we can't be really helpful.

Comment: @Marc, this statement `NSLog(@"%@", [self.contactsArray objectAtIndex:0])` cannot confirm that your contactsArray is correct. Use this to verify again: `NSLog(@"%@", [[self.contactsArray objectAtIndex:0]firstName])`

Comment: To all, thanks for your help, I discovered a minute ago that I re-initialized the  `array ` in the  `viewDidLoad ` in the  `AllContactsViewController ` therefore I think the values were overwritten right after I received them. I deleted the line and now I see the object properties listed correctly in the  `tableview `. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Several things to check:

1) How does your property declaration of `allContactsArray` in `AllContactsViewController` look like? Is it `@property(retain)`?

2) You are not forced to subclass `UITableViewController` although it makes your life easier. In your case be sure that the delegates `delegate` and `dataSource` of your `UITableView` are set correctly.

3) The piece of code `NewContact *tempContact = [[NewContact alloc]init];` is not necessary at all, because you get your object from your array.

4) Remove the line of code `[tableView reloadData];`

5) Be sure that the delegate method `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` is implemented correctly

Comment: #1 doesn't matter, #2 neither (OP mentions that he checked the data source).

Comment: 1) strong, nonatomic 2) Both is set to AllContactsViewController. 3) How can I access then the ivars in the objects in the array? 4) Done, still not working.

Comment: ad 5) Attention: This is another method where you have to return the number of rows you want to display in your table.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the view controller, its array is initially empty, so from the data source methods, the table view gets the information that the number of rows in (any) section is zero - it'll thus never call the data source for cells to be displayed. Possible solutions:

One. After calling `nAllCVC.allContactsArray = self.contactsArray;`, call `[nAllCVC.tableView reloadData];` (assuming nAllCVC exposes its table view through that property), or better:

Two. Instead of @synthesize-ing the data array of the table view, provide a custom getter and setter that calls the table view automagically; something like this:

```
- (NSArray *)allContactsArray {
    return _allContactsArray;
}

- (void)setAllContactsArray:(NSArray *)a {
    if (_allContactsArray == a) return;

    [_allContactsArray release];
    _allContactsArray = [a retain];

    [_tableView reloadData];
}
```

P. s.: you're confusing pointers with the memory pointed to by them. `NewContact *tempContact = [[NewContact alloc]init];` is superfluous and is leaking memory.

P. p. s.: don't reload the table view upon requesting every and each cell, that may end up in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

To all, thanks for your help, I discovered a minute ago that I re-initialized the `array` in the `viewDidLoad` in the `AllContactsViewController` therefore I think the values were overwritten right after I received them. I deleted the line and now I see the object properties listed correctly in the `tableview` . Have a nice day